# Fetching data from MySql tables properly

Tags: jquery, mysql, join

There are two simple tables. Structure of the table at the output will be as follows: 
| Date | Hosts | Hits | Sum_Payin | Merchant_Id |

Date - unique (sum and count by each date) 
Hosts - number of unique hosts on each date on Merchant_Id = 8 
Hits - hits, the sum of hits on each host on each date on Merchant_Id = 8 
Sum_Payin - the sum of payments for each date on Merchant_Id = 8 
How to do a select query properly between 2014-03-01 and 2014-03-31? 
I need data on each day. 
Thanks for your suggestions!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hosts` (
`date` date NOT NULL,
  `host` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `merchant_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hits` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`host`),
  KEY `merchant_id` (`merchant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `hosts` (`date`, `host`, `merchant_id`, `hits`) VALUES
('2014-03-01', 2, 8, 3),
('2014-03-01', 4, 8, 2),
('2014-03-03', 5, 8, 5),
('2014-03-07', 6, 8, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payments` (
`date` date NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `payin` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `merchant_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`customer_id`),
  KEY `merchant_id` (`merchant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `payments` (`date`, `customer_id`, `payin`, `merchant_id`) VALUES
('2014-03-01', 2, 200.00, 8),
('2014-03-02', 3, 300.00, 8),
('2014-03-06', 3, 100.00, 8),
('2014-03-07', 5, 250.00, 8);
```

Comment: CREATE and INSERT statements are just source data for sample

Comment: How make a query that gives us data on each day between 2014-03-01 and 2014-03-31?

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo <kbd>**[SQLFiddle Demo result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a2b41/12)**</kbd>

#### Query

```
select hosts.date,
        hosts.host,
        hosts.hits,
        sum(payments.payin) as Sum_Payin,
        hosts.merchant_id 
        FROM hosts
        INNER JOIN payments ON 
        payments.merchant_id = hosts.merchant_id
        WHERE hosts.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-31';
```

Another demo if you want to get this record `date` Grope wise <kbd>**[check this demo jsFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a2b41/13)**</kbd>

hope this help you!

Comment: And how make a query that gives us data on each day between 2014-03-01 and 2014-03-31?

Comment: oky i missing to reading your question last line. now i update answer with add range between 01 march t0 31 march

Comment: Just about. [Please, check out my own version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0ce9/1). To implement i needed another table 'calendar'. In your opinion is this an optimal query? Thanks.

Comment: I think your query is really good using left join. i think no need to optimal is this already optimal. :)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on your comment from the answer above:

```
SELECT hosts.date,
        hosts.host,
        hosts.hits,
        SUM(payments.payin) as Sum_Payin,
        hosts.merchant_id 
        FROM hosts
        INNER JOIN payments ON 
        payments.merchant_id = hosts.merchant_id
        WHERE hosts.date >= 2014-03-01
        AND hosts.date <= 2014-03-31
        GROUP BY hosts.date;
```